# BasicScrollBarUI: Label instead of Button - Can't scroll

Tags: java, swing, custom-component, listeners, jscrollbar

I have made a custom BasicScrollBarUI.
I have replaced the incrButton / decrButton by JLabels.

Therefore i had to override the InstallListeners(), to add the Listener to the incr/decrLabel instead of the JButtons.

```
    //TODO
    protected void installListeners() {
    trackListener = createTrackListener();
    buttonListenerCustom = createArrowButtonListenerCustom();
    modelListener = createModelListener();
    propertyChangeListener = createPropertyChangeListener();

    scrollbar.addMouseListener(trackListener);
    scrollbar.addMouseMotionListener(trackListener);
    scrollbar.getModel().addChangeListener(modelListener);
    scrollbar.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
    //      scrollbar.addFocusListener(getHandler());

    if (incrLabel != null) {
        incrLabel.addMouseListener(buttonListenerCustom);
        System.out.println("OK gemacht");
    }
    if (decrLabel != null) {
        decrLabel.addMouseListener(buttonListenerCustom);
    }

    scrollListener = createScrollListener();
    scrollTimer = new Timer(scrollSpeedThrottle, scrollListener);
    scrollTimer.setInitialDelay(300); // default InitialDelay?
}
```

Therefore i had to override the ArrowButtonListener, to react on the Labels.

```
protected class ArrowButtonListenerCustom extends MouseAdapter {

    boolean handledEvent;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!scrollbar.isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }
        // not an unmodified left mouse button
        // if(e.getModifiers() != InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) {return; }
        if (!SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
            return;
        }

        int direction;
        if (e.getSource() == incrLabel) {
            direction = 1;
            incrLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(increaseButtonPressedImage));
        } else {
            direction = -1;
            decrLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(decreaseButtonPressedImage));
        }

        scrollByUnit(direction);
        scrollTimer.stop();
        scrollListener.setDirection(direction);
        scrollListener.setScrollByBlock(false);
        scrollTimer.start();

        handledEvent = true;
        if (!scrollbar.hasFocus() && scrollbar.isRequestFocusEnabled()) {
            scrollbar.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        scrollTimer.stop();
        handledEvent = false;
        scrollbar.setValueIsAdjusting(false);
        incrLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(increaseButtonImage));
        decrLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(decreaseButtonImage));
    }
}
```

Of course createArrowButtonListenerCustom() returns a new instance of ArrowButtonListenerCustom.

Now my Problem:

When I click on the incr/decrLabel, the List scrolls correctly, but the thumb of the ScrollBar doesn't move (or better: the Thumb isn't repainted. If I move the Mouse over the thumb, it gets repainted on the right place). I have the same problem, when I scroll with the MouseWheel.

I don't understand, why this doesn't work. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where's the `scrollTimer`?  Does it call `repaint` on each "tick"?

Comment: I have found my error: I overrode the Protected void layoutVScrollbar(JScrollBar sb) from jre6, but used jre7. In jre7 there is a repaint.

Comment: :P don't you just love that